# Check user logged in from outside of WP folder

Tags: wp-load.php, authorization

If user is logged in to site/subsite, and you check this function:

```
require(__DIR__."/wp-load.php");
var_dump(is_user_logged_in());
```

it returns true. However, if called from outside folder:

```
require(__DIR__."/subfolder/wp-load.php");
var_dump(is_user_logged_in());
```

It doesn't recognize authorization. What are the acceptable ways to achieve that, without using REST-API?
(I doubt it just needs pointing some sub-directory for cookie).

Answer (score 1):

If WordPress is installed in `/subfolder/`, then the authentication cookies will by default only valid for that path.

So if needed, you can allow the cookies in parent directory by setting the [cookie constants like `COOKIEPATH`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#additional-defined-constants).

For example, if I had WordPress installed at `example.com/wp/` and I wanted the authentication works at `example.com/`, then I'd define the following in `wp-config.php`: (but I don't know much about the differences between the `SITECOOKIEPATH` and `COOKIEPATH`, other than that the former seems to be specific to Multisite)

```php
define( 'COOKIEPATH',        '/' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH',    '/' );
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp/wp-admin' );
```

But the thing is, you'd need to logout first before applying the above changes, and so does with all other users who were already logged-in on your site, i.e. log out *before* you applied the above changes.

So you'd want to just invalidate all (existing) WordPress cookies by changing the [security keys like `LOGGED_IN_KEY`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#security-keys) — all users will have to login again, but at least, they'd be able to login properly.